# How to passing Date between two Storyboard with didSelectRowAtIndexPath(in Swift)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, didselectrowatindexpath

I  need to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to pass 
my current Cell after Searching (this is the only way that I found),
but how can I pass this cell name to the SecondViewController?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   if(tableView ==   self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView){
    if let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath){
        if let cellTextLabel: UILabel = cell.textLabel{                         
           let  cellSelected = cellTextLabel.text!   

   }
  }
}
```

In the SecondViewController, I need to use the TextView to present the current text to the selected cell.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   if(tableView ==   self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView){
    if let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath){
        if let cellTextLabel: UILabel = cell.textLabel{                         
           let  cellSelected = cellTextLabel.text!  
           // pass your segue name
           self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToDetailVC", sender: cellTextLabel.text!)
   }
  }
}
```

pass data

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "segueToDetailVC")
        {
            var str: String = sender as! String
            // your ViewController class object
            var detail: DetailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailVC
            // pass text in String Variable
            detail.text = str
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting Fehler "cannot assign a value of type String zo value of type UITextView", do you have any Idea?

Comment: the Fehler ist in Detail.text = str

Answer (score 1):

Add an attribute secondViewController in the destination view controller, and use prepareForSegue

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
      if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
           var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as secondViewController;

           svc.toPass = cellTextLabel.text

       }
    }
```

in secondViewController you can define one variable like String

```
var toPass:String!
```

In the secondViewController under the viewDidLoad function add this code

```
println(\(toPass))
```

Comment: The Problem is that in this Way is not posable because my Tree of cell changing when i use the search, this is not usable to use the cell textLabel.text.

Comment: This is my Code in dem Link, Thanks