# Design Navigation Item right bar button with segue to another VC while passing data

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Right now I've this done programmatically. First I'm creating a button in my `UITableViewController` subclass.

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.add, target: self, action: Selector(("onNew")))
}
```

Then

```
func onNew() {
    self.pushViewController(userForm, animated: true)
}
```

**Question/Problem**: I want to change this implementation and no long want to use code but instead options from XCode Design Interface. But I'm not finding any option in my Navigation Controller Attribute window to add a button using design interface. ***(screenshot 1 & 2)***

**Attempt** I tried to drag and drop a Bar Button Item from objects to Navigation Controller but it always sit next to First Responder or exit. ***(screenshot 3)***

**P.S.**: To pass data I through segues I've the solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852554/how-to-passing-date-between-two-storyboard-with-didselectrowatindexpathin-swift).

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit Screenshot 4:** to Describe that I'm embedding a `UITableViewController` within `UINavigationController`. Any workaround to this exception.

[image]

Comment: Please follow this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207846/pass-data-through-segue)

Comment: that's not the question, please read carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a `UINavigationItem` to the `UITableViewController`
2. Add the `UIBarButtonItem` to the `UINavigationItem`

I just added a `UITableViewController` to my storyboard and followed these steps and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add Bar Button Item to View Controller not on the navigation controller.

Here screen shot attached for your reference.

I hope this will help you.

[image]

Comment: I'm using `UITableViewController`, any workaround to this, added a screenshot 4 in my question edit. I'm not using `UIViewController`

Comment: I have tried with UITableViewController instead of UIViewController and it worked with same process.